# Import functions from Python script in remote directory via a custom module

Tags: python, module, python-import, sys

So this problem is a bit convoluted, but I will try to explain.  I have written a script `script.py` that is located in `/my/directory/script.py`.  This contains many helpful functions that I would like to make available to users of Python on this server.  Normally, I would package it as a module and move it to the `libs` folder and access it this way, but unfortunately at my company I am unable to edit files when they are placed there as I will not have root access.

What I have been doing to access this script from either the shell or other scripts is to write:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/my/directory')
from script import *
```

This works, but ideally I would like it to just be:

```
import script
```

What I was thinking was making a folder in `libs` with `__init__.py` that contains the import sys code above, and simply referencing this script with an import.  But when I do this I get an import error that the script is unable to import from my referenced script.

Is there a better way to do this?

**Basically I want people to be able to access my module as if it is installed normally by importing a script that imports my functions.**

Comment: Just tell them to export PATH=$PATH:yourdir and make sure your script has correct permissions. Ideally why not just copy/paste certain versions into libs and then update it when you update your script. It's better that way when you do releases versus constant updates.

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys
import my.directory.script
sys.modules['script'] = my.directory.script
```

run this in `__init__.py`

Comment: FYI: This question is 4 years old and the provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Answer (score -2):

You can use pip to install package locally

```
pip install --user package
```